# How do I find the surface area of this function $y = e^{-x^2}$ when it's rotated around the y-axis?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have this question:

> Set up an integral for the area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about the *y* axis.

So I have the x-axis solution:

$y = e^{-x^2}$ from $ -1 \leq x \leq 1$

I'm going to use the formula:

$$\int_{-1}^1 2 \pi e^{-x^2} \sqrt{1 + \frac{dy}{dx}^2} dx$$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{-x^2} * -2x$ and so $\frac{dy^2}{dx} = 4x^2e^{-2x^2}$

Is that right? Did I do the squaring right?

So surface area = $$\int_{-1}^1 2 \pi e^{-x^2} \sqrt{1 + 4x^2e^{-2x^2}}dx$$

But what about the y-axis?

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem? Do you have any reason to believe that this question has a nice answer, let alone that the integrand has a closed form antiderivative?

Comment: The question you wrote just says to set up the integral -- it doesn't ask you to evaluate it (most of these sorts of surface area problems end up with integrals we can't evaluate exactly). Also yes, you did the squaring right.

Comment: What's this site for exactly @TheGreatDuck?

Comment: Homework questionsthat I'm stuck on adds to that corpus of info in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rotating the curve defined by the function $y=e^{-x^2}$ (with $-1\leq x\leq 1$) about the $y$-axis, you need to restrict the values of $x$ so that you can write (one half piece of) the curve as $x=g(y)$ for some function $g$ and find the corresponding range for $y$.

Then you use the formula
$$
\int_a^b2\pi y\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\ dy
$$

Now, to get the function $g$, you either consider $x\in[0,1]$ or $x\in[-1,0]$ for the function $y=f(x)$ since if you consider all $x\in[-1,1]$, then you can not write $x$ as a function of $y$. Let us consider $x\in[0,1]$. Then $y\in [e^{-1}, 1]$.

Then 
$$
\ln y=-x^2
$$
implies by the chain rule that
$$
\frac{1}{y}=-2x\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}=-2 (\sqrt{-\ln y}) \cdot\frac{dx}{dy}
$$
which tells you that
$$
\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2=\frac{1}{-4y^2\ln y}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems about right for the rotation around the x-axis.

As to the y-axis, I assume you rotate the positive part of your curve ($0 \leq x \leq 1$) around the axis?

If so, try to express $x$ as a function of $y$ (which is valid, because $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$ is bijective on this interval). And then, it is going to be the same formula, except you now integrate $x$ as a function of $y$ instead of the opposite :)

Comment: I'm stuck integrating. I have $lny = lne^{-x^2}$ and $lny = -x^2$ but where do I go from here?

Comment: You probably don't need to evaluate the integral, just have to set it up.