# How do I find the derivative of $y = e^{-x^2}$ with respect to $y$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the derivative of $y = e^{-x^2}$ with $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ Can I take the log of both sides?

$$\ln y = -x^2$$

From here, can I say that $-x^2$ is always = $x^2$? If so, I get:

$$\ln y = x^2 \implies \sqrt{\ln y} = x$$

What's the derivative?

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\ln y^{\frac{-1}{2}} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{2y \sqrt{\ln y}}$$

Is that right?

Comment: To differentiate $y=e^{-x^2}$, you can simply use the chain rule. Also, you can't just change $-x^2$ to $x^2$ (note that $\ln y$ can be negative).

Comment: $-x^2 \neq x^2$ unless $x=0$.  (You are thinking of $(-x)^2 = x^2$)

Comment: What do you mean by "in terms of $x$"? The derivative with respect to $x$? Having an equation of $y' = $ (stuff in terms of $x$)? You have to be clear.

Comment: One uses `\ln y` for typing the logarithm function.

Comment: Have you learnt how to differentiate exponential functions? It seems like you have learnt the chain rule and power rule, so if so, you should have all the tools you need to differentiate $y=e^{-x^2}$ via the chain rule.

Comment: Hardly can I guess what you really want. If you could provide any example that is similar to what you want, that would be helpful.

Comment: Very strange question: it seems that you know the answer according to what you asked two hours ago: [How do I find the surface area of this function $y = e^{-x^2}$ when it's rotated around the y-axis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156119/9464)

Comment: Voting to close this unless OP can explain what he means by "with respect to $x$."  For most people, this would mean $\frac{dy}{dx} = -2x e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: I think what OP really wants is $\frac{dx}{dy}$. You can check the the linked question in my previous comment. I believe he just does not know how to call $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and not realize that $y=e^{-x^2}$ cannot be written as $x=y(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Just my two cents. `:-)`

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean... This is a sticky mess. Personally, @Jwan622, if Jack is right in his assertion, I would recommend trying to figure out the words to more precisely and clearly state what you're looking for and where you're stuck. I would normally recommend editing your question but that's generally not recommended in this scenario - it would change the very nature of the question and invalidate the others' answers and MSE doesn't like that. Once you've more concretely got it down as to where you're stuck, you could probably then open up a separate question.

Comment: I meant respect to y... sorry everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to differentiate

$y = e^{-x^2} \tag 1$

that I know is *via* the chain rule, setting

$u = -x^2; \tag 2$

then

$y = e^u, \tag 3$

and so

$y' = \dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx} = e^u(-2x) = -2xe^{-x^2}. \tag 4$

Some folks like *logarithmic differentiation*, *viz*

$\ln y = -x^2, \tag 5$

and so

$\dfrac{y'}{y} = (\ln y)' = -2x, \tag 6$

or

$y' = -2xy = -2xe^{-x^2}, \tag 7$

which as anticipated agrees with (4).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. It's called logarithmic differentiation. Take logs of both sides and differentiate them with respect to $x$. You don't need to square or take the square root of anything. And there are also no domain issues either: $e^{-x^2}>0$. You can take the log of that without any problem. Here are the steps:

$$\begin{align}
y&=e^{-x^2}\\
\ln{y}&=\ln{e^{-x^2}}\\
\ln{y}&=-x^2\ln{e}\\
\ln{y}&=-x^2\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln{y}\right)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-x^2\right)\\
\frac{1}{y}y'&=-2x\\
y'&=-2yx\\
y'&=-2e^{-x^2}x
\end{align}$$

Thus: $$\left(e^{-x^2}\right)'=-2xe^{-x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just use the chain rule. Let $f(x) = -x^2, g(x) = e^x$ for simplicity's sake. Then

$$y = e^{-x^2} = (g \circ f)(x)$$

Thus,

$$y' = (g(f(x))' = g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$$

Since $g'(x) = e^x, f'(x) = -2x$, then

$$y' = e^{-x^2} \cdot (-2x) = -2xe^{-x^2}$$

---

To address your particular approach, $-x^2 \neq x^2$. This touches on the whole "$-x^2$ is not $(-x)^2$" debacle. Basically, $-x^2$ means $(-1) \cdot x^2$. Notice how this creates issues when you start taking the square root.

Also in your derivative step you wrote $dx/dy$ when you probably meant $dy/dx$.

---

**EDIT:** A further issue: $\sqrt{\ln y}$ is not $\ln{y^{1/2}}$. Note that $\ln(y^a) = a \ln(y)$, that meaning that the power has to be *inside* the logarithm, not applied on the logarithm altogether.

**EDIT $2$:** I won't really comment on the rest since the $-x^2$ debacle and the rest basically makes the rest of your approach invalid. The broad idea - taking the natural logarithm and using implicit differentiation - **is valid**, you just applied it wrong as shown in Michael Rybkin's answer. In summary:

$$y = e^{-x^2} \implies \ln y = \ln e^{-x^2} = -x^2 \implies (\ln y)' = \frac{y'}{y} = -2x = (-x^2)$$

By $y'/y = -2x$, then $y' = -2xy$. Substitute in our definition for $y$ to get our answer, same as the one per the chain rule.